# Dealing with foreign key in create view in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

and those serializers

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('pk', 'name')

class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foo = ???
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ('pk', 'foo', 'name')
```

I need a create api `/bar/create` for `Bar` objects such as :

- I only give the `Foo` primary key in input json
- I retrieve the `Bar` object with `foo` serialized with the `FooSerializer`.

So, let's consider i have this `Foo(pk=1, name='foo')` object in db, i would like to do:

- Request:

  - POST /bar/create
  - content= `{'foo': 1, 'name': 'bar'}`
- Response

  - `{'foo': {'pk': 1, 'name': 'foo'}, 'name': 'bar'}`

How can i do it simply?
Is it a good practice to do this way?

Comment: a) there is no need to specify the primary keys in the serializers' fields. b) the HTTP verb specifies the action, e.g. create, so there is no need to include it in the URI (just POST to `/bar/`). c) the response can include the link to the referenced object, no need to embed it. See [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/). Note: all this is pretty automatic in DRF. Remove `foo = ???` from your model. Use the browsable API to see what goes on.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to [alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) the field into the nested object and make the aliased nested object read-only:

```
class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foo_obj = FooSerializer(required=False,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ('pk', 'foo', 'foo_obj', 'name')
```

If `foo` is present, then it is placed in `Bar`'s `foo_obj` field.  On the client side, you'll have to keep `foo` and `foo_obj` in sync', which really stinks.

Answer (score 0):

1. How can it be done: one way to achieve this is to play around with 2 serializers, which you will select based on the request type:

```python
    class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Bar
            fields = ('pk', 'foo', 'name')

    class BarNestedSerializer(BarSerializer):
        class Meta(BarSerializer.Meta):
            depth = 2


    class BarView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        queryset = Bar.objects.all()

        def get_serializer_class(self):
            return BarNestedSerializer if self.action == 'list' else BarSerializer
```

2. How it should be done: have a separate route for Foo objects, which you will cache on the front-end and display their lookup value based on the ID. At the end of the day, it really depends on your usecase, but normally one should be able to avoid nesting, only if strictly necessary.